# VNC Not Seeing Gnome Desktop in Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, vnc, gnome, centos7

I have a linux box running CentOS 7, which I installed in bash only mode (so it just boots straight into the command prompt), which I am using as a file server. I could do with having a GUI for certain tasks, although this is only required remotely.

I installed VNC as well as Gnome using yum groupinstall Desktop, which all seemed to go ok. I have set up VNC server which I can connect to, however all I get is a grey screen with an x style window box, that I can't really do anything with. I have set up xstartup to launch gnome (I believe) but it still doesn't seem to want to load. xstartup is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

#unset SESSION_MANAGER
#unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
#exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#twm &
exec gnome-session &
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be? I've done plenty of googling around and this setup seems to be working for others - so all I can think is it might have something to do with me installing gnome after the initial install and the fact that the box doesn't boot into gnome normally?

Thanks in advance!

Stuart!

[What i'm seeing when I connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDkuu.png)

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: You need to look in the .vnc folder for a ${hostname}*.log file. If read that it is likely complaining about missing packages or dbus.